# Timed text editor

Tags: exams, software, cheating, tools, assessment

Looking for a very specific tool.

I want to give my students a link to a text editor.
When they open that link, they see a question and instantly a countdown timer starts.

Once the timer is over, whatever the students have written is saved and I can review it.

Is there such a tool?

Comment: To close voters: beware that software recommendations which are specific to academia and teaching are now considered on-topic, see [this FAQ](https://academia.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3658/20058).

Comment: I suspect that a solution would put the timer on the web page, not in the editor. The page would invoke some kind of form editor (maybe even a google doc) and close itself after the specified time. Some academic environments (blackboard? canvas?) may even offer this.

Comment: See [this app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.create.aozora.examtimer&hl=en&gl=US) or [this webpage](https://onlineexamhelp.eklavvya.in/define-online-exam-timer-question/) or [this one](https://www.testinvite.com/lang/en/best-online-exam-management-system-software/best-exam-maker/online-exam-timer-time-limit-section-page-test-question.html).

Comment: My advice would be not to use such a thing. It will disadvantage some students over others. The system is currently bad enough without adding this.

Comment: @Buffy That seems a very weak argument, "it will disadvantage some students over others". What doesn't? Even asking a question disadvantages the students who don't know the answer. And asking them on paper disadvantages the students who can read and write more slowly.

Comment: Google Docs can surely be used in an equivalent fashion.

Comment: @FedericoPoloni, so your argument is that adding disadvantages is fine.

Comment: @Buffy No, I did not make an argument; I merely pointed out that yours seems weak, without further qualifications on what these "disadvantages" are and why they are unacceptable in this context. If you are thinking about students with disabilities, note that there are well-established procedures to compensate for them, such as adding more time.

Comment: No, I don't mean those with disabilities. Testing is an already stressful situation for some students, good and bad. Some panic. Adding a countdown clock to the mix, whether visible or not, just adds to the stress. And if you "get" the answer at the last second and can't enter it, the stress level goes up as you start the next question. There is no reason to add stress and possibly induce panic in some students. And, they aren't the ones who would fail anyway. It would drive me crazy and I was a pretty good student. Of course if you want answers without thinking and are just testing (more)

Comment: (continuing @FedericoPoloni) what is at the tip of the tongue (mind), then fine. But that isn't very deep knowledge. Again. Just. Say. No.

Comment: @Buffy That sounds more like a valid argument now. I can agree with you if the time is very short, like 2 minutes. But that does not disqualify the method completely in my view; just give a reasonable time. Timed exams have been in use forever, even in class before the pandemic, and I don't think they are intrinsically unfair.

Comment: @FedericoPoloni, again, no. "Reasonable" by whose definition. The one setting the time is making assumptions for a group of people. The assumptions will be valid for some but not for others, disadvantaging them. An overall timed test is _already_ a compromise,. Changing the granularity of the timing makes it worse. Changing the rules like this changes the conditions to something people aren't familiar with. We should be trying to make testing more valid and more 'fair', not less. With the typical timed test, students can spend more or less time on a given question, making tradeoffs.  more..

Comment: But with individual timings, students can only effectively answer questions that they can answer quickly (relative to difficulty) and don't have to ponder. The others never get answered. Once more, with feeling. _Just. Say. No._

Comment: @Buffy I beg to disagree. There are situations in any workplace where one should be able to work with definite and very strict time constraints. And one should be trained on this also at the university. When I was a student there was even a professor who brought the alarm clock at the exam: the exam was open book, but each exercise was strictly timed and you would have had to index the material in the book very carefully and train a lot at home to be able to finish on time. Indeed, the failure rate was around 80%, but it was quite instructive on how to work under definite time constraints.

Comment: @Buffy I also find the idea of relaxing time constraints a bit too common among mathematicians. It's something that I observed also in collaborating with a couple of them. But there are many situations in engineering, also during research, where you absolutely cannot take your time, disadvantage or not. So, better learn this kind of stress early at the cost of discomforting the students.

Comment: Discomforting, or disadvantaging? Not the same @MassimoOrtolano. And if that is a needed skill then _teach_ it. Don't just make exams more stressful. That would be a completely different question.

Comment: @Buffy Testing is part of the teaching.

Comment: @MassimoOrtolano Yes, but testing without prior teach is problematic. Especially at the level that I think the OP is involved in. And I think you are now drifting farther and farther from what is right and reasonable.

Comment: @Buffy I find your point of view a bit too disconnected from the needs of many industrial realities where many fresh graduates will find themselves in various unreasonable situations. I had firsthand experience about this, and also from discussions with friends and acquaintances who work in engineering industries, who complain that we don't stress enough the students to prepare them for the battles outside.

Comment: I also want to pipe in as the asker. For our use case, time is not a disadvantage at all. The question should take anyone less than 5min to answer. We would give 15min. The time limit is there only to prevent googling of the answer, or asking online (though would not prevent a ready friend helping out). In fact, if a person cannot answer the question in 10 minutes that should be an automatic disqualification.

Answer (score 8):

Qualtrics surveys allows this.
Create a new survey and just combine a textbox and a timer and choose "show timer" and speicfy an auto-advance time.

This would also allow you to include multiple questions and the data would be stored for you to download.

Many universities have site licences to Qualtrics.

https://www.qualtrics.com/support/survey-platform/survey-module/editing-questions/question-types-guide/advanced/timing/

[image: qualtrics timer]

Comment: Is there an option to not show the timer? Or to just record start and end times?